# Phoneme mode input to speech synthesizer on OS X

Tags: macos, text-to-speech

Working on the built-in speech synthesis of OS X, which can be tested quite easily directly from the command line by using the `say` command.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SpeechSynthesisProgrammingGuide/FineTuning/FineTuning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004365-CH5-SW12), the following string should provide improved pronunciation:

```
My name is [[inpt PHON]] AY1yIY2SAX [[inpt TEXT]].
```

This works from the command line with the voice "Alex":

```
say -v Alex 'My name is [[inpt PHON]] AY1yIY2SAX [[inpt TEXT]].'
```

However, if you try it with another voice, such as "Samantha", it does not seem to work:

```
say -v Samantha 'My name is [[inpt PHON]] AY1yIY2SAX [[inpt TEXT]].'
```

Samantha (or "Sam" to her friends) ignores the command in the double square bracket and just spells out the phonemes as latin letters. Not what I wanted.

Note that Sam does recognise other commands in the string:

```
say -v Sam 'The code is [[nmbr LTRL]] 1989[[nmbr NORM]].'
```

As opposed to:

```
say -v Sam 'I was born in 1989.'
```

So the question is: Is there a way to get Sam and other stubborn voices to change the pronunciation or to accept phonemic input?

I have tested this on OS X 10.11.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, phoneme input doesn’t work with the Nuance voices. It’s a shame.

Comment: Good catch. How can I tell which voices are from Nuance?

Comment: As a first approximation, all voices you download via System Preferences are Nuance. There are other voices available for purchase. The ones from Acapela are pretty good. Those may work. I have only tested them on iOS, though.